# When running confluence via CLI, where does tomcat retrieve its variables from

Tags: spring-boot, shell, tomcat, confluence

I am trying to run a confluence server on command line, however even on an empty project I seem to be getting errors due to GC. Because of that I was trying to increase the amount of memory available to the JVM for confluence, but I'm not sure where these values are being set for the tomcat server. As can be seen below they are being read from somewhere but I'm not sure where:

[Logs with the command line arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j16a.png)

For context I am running atlas-run after doing a fresh install of a plugin by doing atlas-build-confluence-plugin

Answer (score 0):

The Confluence and embedded Tomcat use environment variables you have in the current session. You can set data in `{CONFLUENCE_HOME}/bin/setenv.sh` - this script can be used to set variables you need for runtime, but it should be done with caution. When using maven plugin atlas-xxx command, you can also set arguments in the plugin config.